# How to use python2 on jupyter notebook

Tags: mac, python3

I am using mac book pro. I am using python3 on jupyter notebook. But in order to use apache-spark I need to use use python2 on jupyter notebook. Is there any way to use both python2 and python3 on mac book pro?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/) website:

> Spark runs on Java 8+, Python 2.7+/**3.4+** and R 3.1+.